# How to parse a JSON array in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the MongoDB C# driver how can I parse a JSON array (string) into `BsonDocument[]`?

We would like to store our mongo aggregation pipelines in separate JSON documents so need a way to parse them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a bad idea if that suits your purposes. Yes the C# driver already supports BSON serialization from a JSON string source:

```csharp
string json = '[
    { "$match: { "foo": "bar" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]';

BsonDocument pipeline = 
    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(json);
```

So you can pull in your aggregation pipeline strings formatted as JSON and use them or manipulate them as BSON documents.

Comment: Which version of the driver?  this doesn't compile for me using the 2.x C# driver. It says it can't implicitly convert BsonArray to BsonDocument.   Explicit casting isn't allowed either.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer's result is a BsonArray, if you need a `BsonDocument[]` you'll do something like

```
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(yourJsonString).Select(p => p.AsBsonDocument)
```

and if you need it as a `List<BsonDocument>`

```
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(yourJsonString).Select(p => p.AsBsonDocument).ToList<BsonDocument>()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The first one returns a `BsonArray`, whether this returns a collection of `BsonDocument` as asked.